# Textbox focus jumps to next textbox automatically on mobile safari(ios 5)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova, mobile

i have form with following input field. when i click on first text box , the focus gets transfer to next textbox.i am using this code in phonegap and running it on iphone(ios 5).please help me out..

```
        <form id="createAccount" name="regForm">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" style="height:40px;" >
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="height:40px;">

            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" style="height:40px;">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="RegPassword" placeholder="Password" style="height:40px;">

         </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove your wrong  inside form, then add tabindex on each input. 
Moreover, do you use any lib? (jquery...?)

Comment: I am using phonegap to make iphone app.

Comment: This is a phonegap application which uses the jquery, backbone.js and Zparse for templating a view.